# Javascript error trying to perform a search filter using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app Im trying perform a search filter on names by partial match from the beginning. Heres an example of what Im trying to do:

Lets say I have a list of names:

```
Ben
James
Adam
Judy
Andy
```

and enter the text `"a"` in my search field, it would return

```
Adam
Andy
```

if I further enter `"an"` in my search field, it would return

```
Andy
```

In my app.js, I have the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    var employees = [
        { name: "Ben", gender: "Male", salary: 55000, city: "London" },
        { name: "Jane", gender: "Female", salary: 62000, city: "Albany" },
        { name: "Rick", gender: "Male", salary: 65000, city: "Los Angeles" },
        { name: "Pam", gender: "Female", salary: 60000, city: "Paris" },
        { name: "Josh", gender: "Male", salary: 68000, city: "Brussels" },
    ];

    $scope.employees = employees;

    $scope.filtered = function (item) {
        if ($scope.searchName == undefined) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith($scope.searchName.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

And in my html page, I have the following line which displays the list of employees:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter: filtered">
```

And the following line which the user inputs the search text:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Name" ng-model="searchName.name"> <br><br>
```

However, when I attempt to test this, I get the error:

```
Error: $scope.searchName.toLowerCase is not a function. (In '$scope.searchName.toLowerCase()', '$scope.searchName.toLowerCase' is undefined)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `ng-model` is set to `searchName.name`, `$scope.searchName`is an object, therefore it has no `.toLowerCase()` function.

You need to adjust your if-case like this:

```
if (item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith($scope.searchName.name.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {}
```

Furthermore, it is advisable to use identity operators instead of equality operators, unless strict identity is explicitly not needed.

Comment: Thank you. I had the ng-model set to "searchName.name" because in that case, the default filter would only search the "name" columns and I assumed that I would need it the same for my custom filter.

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-model` is set to searchName.name, so you may need to call on `$scope.searchName.name.toLowerCase()` instead of `$scope.searchName.toLowerCase()`